# How to use get elements by class name and then by id in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyclassname

What I ultimately want to do is find a link in a div with a known class name and change it. I'm stuck on properly getting the content of the link and cannot figure out my mistake. Using getElementsByClassName and getElementsByTagName seemed to both work separately but will not work when I use them together. I've never used jquery before so I don't feel comfortable going that route.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="test">
<a href="http://www.google.com">LINK</a></div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Test it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var x=document.getElementsByClassName("test");
x.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerHTML="Hello World";
document.write(x[0]);
};

</script>
```

Comment: I suspect that solving exactly _this_ kind of problem is actually why jQuery was invented.  You may want to reconsider going that route.  Otherwise you will need to write a recursive DOM traversal yourself, which is how jQuery does it in old browsers.

Comment: To clarify. `x` is a collection of DOM elements. Collections do not have very many properties. For example, they do not have the `getElementsByTagName` method. That's why your code fails. David Thomas has good solutions.

Comment: From my limited js/html/whatever knowledge: Don't use `document.write` once the site has loaded. Remove that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In compliant browsers you could simply use `document.querySelector()`:

```
var x = document.querySelector('.test > a');
x.innerHTML = 'Hello world';
```

`document.querySelector` returns a single element (the only element, or the first of multiple elements), rather than a `nodeList`/collection (returned by `getElementsByTagName()` and `getElementsByClassName()`).

Incidentally, with jQuery:

```
$('.test > a').html('Hello world'); // sets the innerHTML of the returned elements
```

Or:

```
$('.test > a').text('Hello world'); // sets the text of the returned elements
```

Comment: or he could use jQuery ;)

Comment: He could, but there's a strong implication that he doesn't want to.

Answer (score 0):

Use the query selector syntax as follows:

```
var x = document.querySelector('div.classname > p');
```

This will result in all `<p>` elements within the `div.classname`.

Comment: In all due respect it might very well be valid to introduce some `JQuery` even though the questioner specify that he/she isn't comfortable with it. no need to insinuate poor programming practice.